# how to auto crop images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am making a manga reader app and i was wondering if there is way to remove page edges ,
for example :

(**please open the images in a new tab so you can see the difference between the two images**)

i want to turn this image  :

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKPGS.png)

into this :

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrsKr.png)

here, i used this [website](https://www4.lunapic.com/editor/?action=smart-crop) to auto crop the image.

Comment: Try to use it: https://29a.ch/2014/04/03/smartcrop-content-aware-image-cropping. And if you want to use on Flutter you probably will need to re-write this is Dart.

Comment: Try to use this to find the first pixel from the top, from the bottom, from the left and from the right. Then you will know the coordinations, then find a way to cut out the image using these coords: https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels

Comment: @stacktrace2234 this package only change the background of a container to match the color of the image ,
package description : `Lets you build a widget that depends on the width and height of some image, and the color of its pixels.`

Comment: Yeah, I said use this package to find where the image starts and ends. Then find a way to crop the image using these coords.